# Upload multipart image with parameters in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am new to IOS n want to upload the image with parameters to server but it's not uploading. I tried a lot refer the alamofire and also base64 but nothing is working for me. Did I miss any thing, any help to understand this?

Thanks in advance. Please help me to resolve issue

Below is my code:

```
@IBAction func submitBtnClicked(_ sender: Any)

{
    //parameters
    var number: Int?
    number = 47000482
    var srNumber = String(format:"%d",number!)
    var urlString: String = filePath!.absoluteString
    var parameters = ["s_no":srNumber, "count":"1"]
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.chosenImage!, 0.5)

    print(parameters)
    print(imgData)

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        multipartFormData.append(imgData!, withName:"filestream", fileName:(self.filePath?.lastPathComponent)!, mimeType: "image/jpeg")

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName:key)
        }
    }, to:"https://********************")

    { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the error? and can you upload whole code so i can debug it?

Comment: proper format your code before posting here.

Comment: Add HttpMethod in request. You can try "Content-Type: Multipart/*" in header.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //MARK: - Multiple Images Uploading API Call
        func serviceUploadMultipleImageData(model : UploadImageResponseModel,isLoader:Bool = true,name:String = "", loaderViewcontoller : UIViewController? = nil,url: String, method: HTTPMethod, InputParameter: Parameters?, ServiceCallBack: @escaping (_ Completion: ServiceResponseNormal, _ isSuccess:Bool)-> Void) {
            let viewContoller = loaderViewcontoller
            guard Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() else {
                Singleton.sharedSingleton.showPopup(title: "No Internet", message: HttpCode.NoInternetConnection.message(), image: nil, VC: viewContoller!)
                ServiceCallBack(self.setCustomResponse(Code: HttpCode.NoInternetConnection.rawValue, Message: "No Internet Connection"),false)
                return
            }
            if isLoader == true {
                if viewContoller != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.startLoading(onView: (viewContoller?.view)!)
                } else {
                    ProgressHUD.startLoading(onView: appDelegate.window!)

                }
            }

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

                for obj in model.arrImages{
                multipartFormData.append(obj.imageData!, withName:obj.imgName, fileName: "", mimeType: "image/jpg")
}
                for (key, value) in InputParameter! {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: true)!, withName: key)
                }
            }, to:url)
            { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):

                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                        model.progress = Progress.fractionCompleted
                    })

                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        if isLoader == true {
                            if viewContoller != nil {
                                ProgressHUD.stopLoading(fromView: (viewContoller?.view)!)
                            }else {
                               ProgressHUD.stopLoading(fromView: appDelegate.window!)
                            }
                        }
                        if(response.result.isSuccess){
                            print(response)
                            do{
                                if response.data != nil{
                                    var responseParsed = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServiceResponseNormal.self, from: response.data!)
                                    if responseParsed.Code == "200"
                                    {
                                        responseParsed.Data = response.data
                                        ServiceCallBack(responseParsed, true)
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Singleton.sharedSingleton.showPopup(title: "Error", message: responseParsed.Message ?? "Error", image: nil, VC: viewContoller!)
                                        ServiceCallBack(responseParsed, false)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch let error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                                var falilure = ServiceResponseNormal()
                                falilure.Data = nil
                                falilure.Message = "Response could not parsed"
                                ServiceCallBack(falilure, false)
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if let error = response.result.error{
                                let message = error.localizedDescription
                                var falilure = ServiceResponseNormal()
                                falilure.Data = nil
                                falilure.Message = message
                                ServiceCallBack(falilure, false)
                                Singleton.sharedSingleton.showPopup(title: "Error", message: message, image: nil, VC: viewContoller!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    let message = encodingError.localizedDescription
                    var falilure = ServiceResponseNormal()
                    falilure.Data = nil
                    falilure.Message = message
                    ServiceCallBack(falilure, false)
                    Singleton.sharedSingleton.showPopup(title: "Error", message: message, image: nil, VC: viewContoller!)
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly  you need to add method type i.e .post or .put type with along with url then you will able to send the image data and also increase the timeout interval for request of session   ***manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120*** If you have any query you reply me on same So I will try to resolve your problem.

```
class func requestForAPI(param:Dictionary<String, String>?, Url:String,image:UIImage,isShowLoader:Bool, headers:[String:String]?,  completion: @escaping (_ result: AnyObject?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

  let reach:Reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()
  let netStatus:NetworkStatus = reach.currentReachabilityStatus()
if (netStatus == NotReachable)
{

    NSUtility.shared().showMessage(title: "Alert!", body: "Please connect to the internet to continue", themetype: .error)

    return
}

if isShowLoader == true{
    APPDELEGATE?.showLoaderView()
}

let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
let  imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)

manager.upload(multipartFormData:
    {
        (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName:    "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg") for (key, value) in param {
             multipartFormData.append(value.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)

}, to:URL(string: Url)!,method:.put, headers:headers)
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload,_,_ ):
        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            //Print progress
        })
        upload.responseJSON
            { response in
                APPDELEGATE?.dismissLoader()

                //print response.result
                if response.result.value != nil
                {

                    print (response.result.value as Any)
                    completion(response.result.value as AnyObject? , nil)
                }
        }
    case .failure(let encodingError):
          print(encodingError)
          completion(nil, encodingError)
        break
    }
}}}
```